# Why is sbt pausing after resolving?

Tags: sbt

Our build server output looks like this

```
[13:24:09][Step 1/1] [info] Loading project definition from ...
[13:24:10][Step 1/1] [info] Set current project ...
[13:24:10][Step 1/1] [info] Updating {file:/Users/build/TeamCity/agents/agent1/work/6060f176dc49a319/}root...
[13:24:11][Step 1/1] [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4 ...
... blah blah
[13:24:16][Step 1/1] [info] Done updating.
[13:26:42][Step 1/1] [success] Total time: 146 s, completed 24-Jul-2014 13:26:42
```

So it took a few seconds to complete the resolving step but then between `Done updating` and the next step there was a pause of a couple of minutes.

Any idea what is going on there?

Comment: It's to give you time to learn Haskell!

Comment: I didn't think of that. It must be why scalac is slow too.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure if it's before or after displaying "Done updating", but two things happen surrounding Ivy resolution: caching and writing resolution reports. Update is called by compile, so caching the result is important. If you have a large dependency graph, the caching the input and output might take few seconds. Ivy resolution reports are written out to `target/resolution-cache/reports/` directory, which tells you exactly what modules and artifacts got resolved. This a large XML file written out for each configurations, so it could also take a few seconds. If you have number of subprojects with large dependencies all this could compound to many seconds.

I'm currently working on several features in sbt to related to this. [Consolidated resolution](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/1454) should ease the pain for multi-project builds if the subprojects have fairly uniform dependencies. Using the result from resolution report, I'll produce eviction warnings.

Comment: I've seen that this issue happens on our build machine which has a weird network set up. On a machine with a good connection there is no pause at all.

Comment: Oh I somehow missed "couple of minutes" part. That's beyond IO overhead of caching and saving XML files.

Answer (score 0):

We've discovered that by completely cleaning our target dir the problem went away :(

We were using

```
  cleanKeepFiles ++= Seq("resolution-cache", "streams").map(target.value / _)
```

which may have been the culprit, who knows.

If it happens again I'll try to understand whats going on.